# Ссылка на содержимое второго таба с другой страницы

Tags: bootstrap, javascript

Имеется такой таб из bootstrap:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Первая вкладка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Вторая вкладка</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
  <p>Содержание первого таба</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
  <p>Содержание второго таба</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Как реализовать ссылку на содержимое второго таба с другой страницы? Пробовал через якорь `site.ru/page.html#profile`, но ссылка выводит на содержимое первого таба.

Comment: мне кажется, в бутстрапе нет такой фичи. хотя на SO говорят убрять class="active" вообще.

Comment: если бы была, то она бы уже по логике работа, по дефолту, все дело в какой-то доп. js функции, я думаю что она уже давно избита может кто поделится. Я как чайник могу понечно через php сделать, регулярку на урл, потом сравнение с хэштегами но кода получается не мало, а вот с js не дружу

Comment: на php вы хэшей не увидите (они на сервер вообще не передаются) :P  попробуйте убрать active, ну или вызывать show tab  в `$(function(){});` хэш лежит в document.location.hash

Comment: у меня есть $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], а значит и хэш :) спасибо, погуглю document.location.hash уже что-то

Comment: ой, ошибочка, в $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] то вырезается #...

Answer (score 2):

Чисто разметкой это не решить. Добавьте скрипт:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
        $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click();
    }
}
```

Comment: что должно было выйти? что-то непонял

Answer (score 0):

С Bootstrap не работала, но на этой [странице](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html) обнаружила интересную штуку, слева закладки для контента расположены в блоке `.bs-docs-sidebar`. А непосредственно в body прописано `<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar">`. Думаю,  `data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar"` влияет на вывод содержимого якоря с других страниц, т.к. ссылка [такого вида](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html#examples) проходит. В вашем случае у списка класс - `"nav nav-tabs"`, может быть стоит прописать `<body data-target=".nav-tabs">`.

Comment: речь не идет об редактировании кода, с таким успехом я могу прописать в классе второго блока active и он станет по умолчанию активным, мне надо чтобы ссылка site.ru/page.html#profile автоматически открывала второй таб

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Сам пытаюсь решить подобную задачу -

Заголовок1

Содержание

Содержание

Заголовок2

Содержание

Содержание

Чтобы из другой страницы по якорю, например, "#panel3" открывалась нужная панель.
Перепробовал многое, но не работает.

```html
   
    <div class="bs-docs-sidebar">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  
  <li class="active dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
      Заголовок1 
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel1">Содержание</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel2">Содержание</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="active dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
      Заголовок2
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel3">Содержание</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel4">Содержание</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
</div>
```